# How to get a floating point number interval of fixed length and bounds in swift?

Tags: swift

In Numpy (python package), one can construct a discrete interval of floating point numbers using the syntax `numpy.linspace(minValue, MaxValue, numberOfSamples)`.

I see swift have `func stride<T>(from start: T, through end: T, by stride: T.Stride)` which allow to get an interval of values whith a fixed step size (stride).

But is there an equivalent of linspace?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found an equivalent of linspace in the standard library, but you can implement it yourself.

```swift
func linspace<T>(from start: T, through end: T, in samples: Int) -> StrideThrough<T>
  where T : FloatingPoint, T == T.Stride {
  return Swift.stride(from: start, through: end, by: (end - start) / T(samples))
}
```

Comment: if `T == T.Stride` then `let delta: T = (end - start) / T(samples)`

Comment: `func linspace<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(from start: T, through end: T, in samples: T) -> StrideThrough<T> where T == T.Stride {
    Swift.stride(from: start, through: end, by:  (end - start) / T(samples))
}`